# Will files served from Cloudfront (after authentication) be cached in Browsers?

Tags: caching, browser, amazon-cloudfront

We are using cloudfront to serve video files & images. We first authenticate the request (using cfsign.pl) and then process the request. So expiring urls are generated for file delivery.

The header set for the files is,

1) cache-control=max-age:8400

My doubt is, whether these files will be cached in the browser or not?

If not, what should we do to make it cached?